# dc.js - horizontal bar chart / row chat, or rotate d3.svg?

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, transform, dc.js

Is there a way to create a horizontal bar chart (or modify the row chat)?

The row chart does almost what I want, however I want the y axis to be a continuous variable and it seems the row chart defines the y axis in terms of discrete/ordinal variables.

I was also thinking about rotating the svg with d3. (Rotating the whole div worked, however the brush effect did not rotate too).

I was thinking:

```
dc.renderAll();

d3.select("body").select("#barChart3").select("svg").attr("transform", function(d) { return "rotate(90)"});
```

however that erased the whole chart rather than rotating it.

Any suggestions?

Update:

I am having some success with rotating the svg (the brush works), however the graph is being cut off and I can't figure out why...

Comment: can you share if you were able to achieve a horizontal Bar chart (row chart) with rotation? also share the mechanism you used for rotating svg. thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two charts are completely different codebases and have different features.  The Y axis of a row chart does not even use a scale, so you are quite right that it can't be made continuous in its present form.

It is an eventual goal to merge them, but for now I think rotating is your best bet.

As for the clipping problem you're having, look for the [clip-path attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/clip-path) on the generated SVG. It would need to be rotated as well, but for a quick fix you can probably remove it.

Comment: Glad I could help. I forgot to mention that I have heard from others (on the user group I think) that they were successful with rotation, although I haven't seen the results.